# accessing the dictionary elements inside a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
 [{'start': '09:00', 'end': '11:00'}, {'start': '12:30', 'end': '12:45'}, {'start': '13:15', 'end': '14:00'}, {'start': '15:00', 'end':'16:45'}, {'start': '16:55', 'end': '17:00'}]
```

I have to fetch the value of first dictionary of value 'end' and the next dictionary of 'start' everytime:

`for each_slot in free_slots:
     for key in each_slot.items():
         if key=='end':
             print(key.val())`

I expect my loop should fetch everytime this kind of output my first loop should fetch the first dictionary 'end':11:00 and start:12:30 and the second iteration should get 'end':12.45 and start:13:15.
 But I am getting an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another solution:

```
l=[{'start': '09:00', 'end': '11:00'}, {'start': '12:30' , 'end': '12:45'}, {'start': '13:15', 'end': '14:00'}, {'start': '15:00', 'end':'16:45'}, {'start': '16:55', 'end': '17:00'}]
    for i in  range(0,len(l)-1):
     print('end:',l[i]['end'],'Start:',l[i+1]['start'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the below and see if it suits your needs.

```py
my_dict = [{'start': '09:00', 'end': '11:00'}, {'start': '12:30' , 'end': '12:45'}, {'start': '13:15', 'end': '14:00'}, {'start': '15:00', 'end':'16:45'}, {'start': '16:55', 'end': '17:00'}] 
processed_list = [{'start':my_dict[x]['start']} if x%2==1 else {'end':my_dict[x]['end']} for x in range(len(my_dict)) ]
print(processed_list)
```

The output as below.

```py
[{'end': '11:00'}, {'start': '12:30'}, {'end': '14:00'}, {'start': '15:00'}, {'end': '17:00'}]
```

All the best.

Comment: It worked ,but my requirement is different so I used the previous .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below. You can get all the `start` and `end` from source data, into a separate list and then shift the start to 1 position and `zip` both the list.

```
data = [{'start': '09:00', 'end': '11:00'}, {'start': '12:30' , 'end': '12:45'}, {'start': '13:15', 'end': '14:00'}, {'start': '15:00', 'end':'16:45'}, {'start': '16:55', 'end': '17:00'}]

starts = list(map(lambda d : d['start'], data))[1:]
ends = list(map(lambda d : d['end'], data))

for v in zip(ends, starts):
    print(v)
```

Output:

```
('11:00', '12:30')
('12:45', '13:15')
('14:00', '15:00')
('16:45', '16:55')
```

Comment: actually like that one, kind of overcomplicated with `lambda` AND `zip` ;-)